# Update image using dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, varbinary

I have been battling with this statement:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[transact_image_update]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@transact_recordID_int int, 
@image1_bin image, 
@image2_bin image, 
@transact_referenceNo_str nvarchar(25),
@userID_last uniqueidentifier,
@tableName nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

DECLARE @sqlUpdt01 nvarchar(4000)
SET @sqlUpdt01  = '
        Update [dbo].[' + @tableName + '] SET [image1_bin] = '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @image1_bin), 2)      
        + ', [image2_bin] = '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @image2_bin), 2)
        +', [userID_last] = '''+ convert(nvarchar(4000),@userID_last)
        + ''' WHERE (transact_recordID_int = '+convert(varchar,@transact_recordID_int) +')
            AND ([transact_referenceNo_str] = ''' +convert(varchar, @transact_referenceNo_str)
             +''' )
             AND (locked_bol = 0) 
             '  
exec sp_executesql @sqlUpdt01
```

Basically, I have many DB tables with similar schema but different names (for types of transactions) and would like this ONE procedure to make the update given the table name as argument.
This script compiles successfully but execution cannot update the image field.
Is there a conversion I'm missing?

Please help.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Please provide more information about what is going wrong

Comment: There are no errors in the script. However, the update does not happen

Comment: Can you print the sql statement and convert the update in a select, so you can test the where clause?

Comment: ---------------------------
The floating point value '474946383961E8021' is out of the range of computer representation (8 bytes).

The identifier that starts with 'A04F700000000000000330000660000990000CC0000FF002B00002B33002B66002B99002BCC002BFF0055000055330055660055990055CC0055FF00800000803' is too long. Maximum length is 128.

Incorrect syntax near 'A04F700000000000000330000660000990000CC0000FF002B00002B33002B66002B99002BCC002BFF0055000055330055660055990055CC0055FF00800000803'. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: you shouldn't need all that to test a where clause

Comment: I have tested the same WHERE clause in other related queries such as Updating only the <locked_bol> field. It works fine. What I simply want to do is for this to work://    Update [dbo].[' + @tableName + '] SET [image1_bin] = ' +@image1_bin     //  I simply want to update the <image> type of field in a dynamic SQL. My input parameter is already a Byte[] in c#

Comment: If you have many tables with the same schema, why not just make many procedures? This can be automated very easily. You could also consider changing from image (deprecated 10 years ago) to varbinary(max), then you can use proper local variables and strongly typed parameters to sp_executesql, instead of this double-convert and concatenation minefield.

Comment: I guess you're right Aaron, I was aware of the deprecated <image> type - it's just that I have to change quite a lot in the UI. I guess there's no short-cut to it.... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the procedure uses `image` parameters instead of `varbinary(max)`, or why you aren't passing the parameter values to `sp_executesql` directly. How about:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[transact_image_update]
  @transact_recordID_int int, 
  @image1_bin varbinary(max),
  @image2_bin varbinary(max), 
  @transact_referenceNo_str nvarchar(25),
  @userID_last uniqueidentifier,
  @tableName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

  SET @sql = N'UPDATE dbo.' 
    + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + N'
    SET [image1_bin] = @i1,
            [image2_bin] = @i2,
            [userID_last] = @u
    WHERE transact_recordID_int = @t
    AND [transact_referenceNo_str] = @s
    AND locked_bol = 0;';

  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql,
    N'@i1 varbinary(max), @i2 varbinary(max), @u uniqueidentifier, 
    @t int, @s nvarchar(25)',
    @image1_bin, @image2_bin, @userID_last,
     @transact_recordID_int, @transact_referenceNo_str;
END
```